# Refreshing Variable Values in a Class

Tags: python, function, class, variables

Within a class in Python:

I have this variable that I pass through a function called "changers"

```
energy_L_gainer = changers('cap_largeover,','sec_energy','-change')
```

When I call upon this variable from another function, how can I get it to pass back through the function again to refresh the data in the variable. I have searched everywhere and tried all that my small mind could muster, and I cannot get it to work. Any ideas? Thank you all so much.

Can you rerun the class somehow within the function to refresh the variables?

I called upon this variable within another function using:
self.energy_L_gainer

Here is the changers function for reference:

```
    def changers(cap, sec, sort):
        screen = requests.get(f'https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f={cap}{sec},geo_usa&ft=4&o={sort}', headers = headers).text
        tables = pd.read_html(screen)
        tables = tables[-2]
        tables.columns = tables.iloc[0]
        tables = tables[1:]
        return tables
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I'm following you, but you probably need to use `self.energy_L_gainer =`  instead of `energy_L_gainer =`. In Python those two aren't the same like they can be in some other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a property on your class

```
@property
def energy_L_gainer(self):
    return changers('cap_largeover,','sec_energy','-change')
```

Now any reference to `self.energy_L_gainer` will use the result of that function